# Scala java compatibily issues in play.

Tags: java, scala

I'm using play 2.5.x, I have a scenario, where i need to use java code in scala controller. But I'm having issue while getting values (implemented interface) of java class.

```
public interface Myinterface {

public static int MY_INTERFACE_VALUE = 10;

}

public class MyJavaClass implements  Myinterface {

}


scala-Controller {

MyJavaClass.MY_INTERFACE_VALUE; // here i'm getting compile time error. 

}

// ErrorMSG:  value MY_INTERFACE_VALUE is not a member of object MyJavaClass
```

i have no idea why i'm getting this error.

Comment: ^ if you have given this link in an answer box, I would have upvoted and accepted your answer  :)

Comment: Thanks, I'm glad it was helpful. A comment like that is generated automatically whenever someone votes to close a question as a duplicate. You can find out more about that at http://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates

Answer (score 2):

It is exactly what your error message states: <s>your princess is in another castle</s> value is not a member of this object.

That static field is a field of the interface, and not it's implementing class. You can use it like this: `Myinterface.MY_INTERFACE_VALUE;`

Comment: I have implemented that interface, so i can access that field with reference to class. Same code is working in java controller.